# How to host jupyter Notebook as subdirectory along with other website

Tags: python, apache, jupyter

I have a linux server, where I have hosted Jupyter Notebook. I can host only 1 website (that too on https). But I have some other Flask or Django based web applications too.

**Can I host Jupyter notebook as a subdomain on some webserver like Apache. So that I am free to host other websites of django or flask over other subdomains of Apache etc.**

Based on my problem, if some alternate solution can be suggested by someone that will also do (i.e., hosting multiple sites including jupyter notebook over just one DNS)

- I have explored options to run multiple notebook servers on same port. People and documentation said it is not possible.

This log shows the port 8888. I have restriction of only one port 443.

```
[I 15:09:00.576 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 15:09:00.577 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=
```

Final result should look like:
https://mysite/notebook  --> jupyter notebook
https://mysite/myweb1    --> Some other html/jquery page running on same server (Can be django or flask app too)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you fix it?

Comment: Not solved yet @Nisba

Comment: I actually solved this. I ran Jupyter with a custom configuration `--config my_config_file.py` where I set `c.ServerApp.base_url = '/my_subdirectory_name'`. I am using JupyterLab, but I think this should work also with standard Jupyter